# Parsing a file by lines and words in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a medium project in C, at some part I need a function that gets a `FILE*` parameter, the file have strict rules (table of data) and I need to parse and store the data line by line and each line I need to parse word by word and use those words.

The problem is that for each line I need to allocate memory according to the number of words in that line, I tried to use `fgets` and `strtok` with the `" "` delim for that and it worked when using it only one time, but `strtok` is breaking when I'm doing it twice (tried to first counting words then allocate the memory and at the end parse the words again and store the data).

Is there a better approach for that function? If not how can I fix the bug with `strtok`?

Data file example:

```
123456789
234123 234567 239875 789406 89044
132456789 98372816
```

I need to scan each int but the line is important, first line represent something and second line represent something else.
The only assumption I can make on the data is:
all numbers wont start with 0.

Second line numbers is maximum MAX_INT.

First and third lines numbers are 9 digits number.

I don't know how much numbers there are in every line

Comment: 'I tried to use fgets and strtok with the " " delim for that' and 'how can I fix the bug with strtok?' --> post that code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` modifies the buffer it breaks into words, so you must make a copy if you wish to parse the line twice.

The pointers returned by `strtok` point to the input line, so you must make copies to store into the array of pointers you allocated. Use `strdup()` for this.

To break the line into space delimited words, you should use `" \t\n"` as a list of delimiters, otherwise the trailing newline stored by `fgets()` will be part of the last word on each line.

Here is an alternative using linked lists for lines and words:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 500

struct Word {
    char *word;
    struct Word *next;
};

struct Line {
    struct Word *head;
    struct Word *tail;
    struct Line *next;
};

struct Line *new_line(void) {
    struct Line *lp = calloc(1, sizeof(*lp));
    if (lp == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate line");
        exit(1);
    }
    lp->head = lp->tail = NULL;
    lp->next = NULL;
    return lp;
}

struct Word *new_word(struct Line *lp, const char *word) {
    struct Word *wp = calloc(1, sizeof(*wp));
    if (wp == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate word");
        exit(1);
    }
    wp->word = strdup(word);
    wp->next = NULL;
    if (lp->head == NULL) {
        return lp->head = lp->tail = wp;
    } else {
        return lp->tail = lp->tail->next = wp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    struct Line *head = NULL;
    struct Line **tailp = &head;

    const char *filename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "filename.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        struct Line *lp = new_line();
        // link the line at the end
        *tailp = lp;
        tailp = &(*tailp)->next;
        char *word = strtok(line, " \t\n");
        while (word != NULL) {
            new_word(lp, word);
            word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (struct Line *lp = head; lp; lp = lp->next) {
        for (struct Word *wp = lp->head; wp; wp = wp->next) {
            printf("%s ", wp->word);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea was to get a line into a buffer with fgets and the using the strtok on the buffet, is there a better and less source demanding then that?

Comment: @3xhaust: reading a line and parsing it with `strtok()` is fine but you must use extra steps: read the line, make a copy, parse it to would the words, allocate the array, parse the copy and store copies of the words allocated with `strdup()`.

Comment: Is it possible to use fscanf with something like %[^\n]d?

Comment: @3xhaust: `%[^\n]d` is probably not what you want... what is your objective? To reliably read all lines, I strongly recommend `fgets()`, or possibly `getline()` if your system supports it.

Comment: The problem is I dont know how many lines I have and I dont know the length of each line (they can ve different) so fgets and buffer can cause problems. I've added example at the original post

Answer (score 1):

First, read all the characters in an array and then tokenize the word based on " ". I have used getc, you can very easily use fgetc to reduce the overhead.

You won't have to worry about words getting split halfway through if you read the whole file into a character array because using MAX_LENGTH can split your words halfway through.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE* file = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); // Open file for reading
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    int c; 
    int text_size = 4;
    char * text = malloc(sizeof(char)*text_size);
    int size = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) { 

        if(size==text_size){
            text_size *= 2;
            text = realloc(text, text_size);
        }

        text[size++] = (char)c;

    }

    char * word = strtok(text, " ");
    while (word != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's very similar to the first code that I wrote but here I'm losing the words without knowing how much there is. Lets say the line has 7 words then I need to allocate array of 7 structs that one of their member will store the data.

Comment: I have made modifications to the solution, I think it will be more useful to you know. I have written a the top what modifications I have made and how you can tailor it further for your needs.